# Is there a way to attach breakpoints to a Django South migration?

Tags: django, django-south, pycharm

I'm having issues with a data migration, and really wish I could place a breakpoint on the problem spot and inspect the object.  Is there a way to accomplish this through PyCharm?

If not, is there any other way to accomplish this?

If not, what's the best way to debug South migrations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in PyCharm. You need to [create](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) Django server [run configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-django-server.html).

There specify *Custom run command* with your south migration command and after that simply press debug button (before placing breakpoints where you want debugger to stop).

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR; Debug any test that has database access. Applies to any migration, not just Django South.

**Long answer:**

Ever wondered why, when running tests, you see the following message?

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'
```

Which, in the case of `pytest`, is a result of the following line that allows database access:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.django_db # <-- This line
def test_my_user():
    me = User.objects.get(username='me')
    assert me.is_superuser
```

Pytest will then give you a super fresh database with all the tables for that test. It does this by running all migrations on a fresh, disposable database.

> The default implementation creates the test database by applying migrations and removes databases after the test run.

(Taken from `pytest-django`'s [documentation](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#django-db-setup))

One way, which is easier (if you already have the ability to debug tests)

- put a breakpoint in the migration
- debug *any* test
- and because Django runs *all migrations on a fresh empty standalone database*, you're automagically debugging the migration.

According to my research, this also [applies to `unittest`](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/09/05/what-happens-when-you-run-manage.py-test).

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitry mentioned one can run the migration command in PyCharm and debug it.
The command is `python manage.py migrate <name of your Django app> <name of the migration>`, e.g. `python manage.py migrate projects 0007_auto_20220407_1105.py`.

In many cases you even don't need breakpoints, just make sure you configure the debugger to break on exceptions.
Here is how it looks in VS Code (sorry for not using PyCharm this time, I use them interchangeably):

[image: a screenshot from VS Code with an SQL exception]

You can see the faulty SQL in `sql` variable, and you can go up the call stack tree to `apply` function and see which `operation` caused this issue:
[image: a screenshot from VS Code with apply function in callstack and contents of operation variable]

Comment: For me, i don't really need full command of `python manage.py migrate`, I just need to set `migrate` in custom command and it's worked.