# Debuging Django Manage.py Custom commands Pycharm

Tags: django, pycharm, django-manage.py

I am trying to learn how to debug a django application with PyCharm. In the application we have several custom manage.py commands. If I run there via terminal (external or Pycharm's terminal) they run fine.

If I try to run them from PyCharm (Tool -> run manage.py task) so I can debug, I get the following error:

```
Unknown command: 'add_question'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I started working on the Django Project before using PyCharm, so I created it via django-admin, and we are adding it to pycharm as OpenDirectory->Select the project.

Any help would be helpful, be it to manage to run the command from inside PyCharm, or to connect PyCharms terminal to the debugger so that I can debug when running from PyCharms terminal.

Comment: Have you enabled "Django Support" (Settings>Django Support) and set the paths for settings and manage?

Comment: Yes. I had several problems at first with PATHs and general configuration parameters I had missed, but they gave the the problems also in the terminal run. I think all these problems are solved as I can run from PyCharms terminal, I just cant to it graphically.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355385/674976), though a little outdated. Quick update for PyCharm 2016.3:

- Run > Run... > Edit Configurations... (Note: you can add configurations by doing both "Run..." and "Debug...")
- Click green + (plus sign)
- In the drop down menu, choose Django Server.
- Check "Custom run command" and enter your command (the part that goes after `manage.py` in the console.
- Make sure "Port" and "Host" are empty. If not—make them empty.
- Change "Name" to your liking.
- "Apply" and "Close"

[image]

Now you can run this configuration (Run > Run... > Your_configuration_name) and debug it (Run > Debug... > Your_configuration_name).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a configuration for a custom command you made

- Select Tools->Edit Configurations.
- In the left column, you will find a list and a "+" button in the upper part. Click this one, then select "Django Server.
- In the right part of the same window, you check "Custom run command", and write your custom command in the box
- Write a name for this configuration and select OK.

Now just run/debug, selecting the configuration you just created.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone still having trouble with this. Try setting up a python run configuration which is more flexible instead of django server configuration. Checkout this [post](http://djangotricks.blogspot.ru/2016/05/debugging-management-commands-in-pycharm.html)